# R Readxl Error, EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Tags: r, readxl

I am trying to load a .xls file on my mac using R studio Version 1.1.383

```
library(readxl);
dataset <- read_excel(NULL)
Error in switch(ext, xls = "xls", xlsx = "xlsx", xlsm = "xlsx", if (nzchar(ext)) { :
EXPR must be a length 1 vector
```

I read elsewhere on Stackoverflow that Switch expects a vector and so the issue is that I am trying to load a data frame but I could not find how to resolve.  I am not yet familiar with the contents of the xls file as it was sent to me to work on and I do not have Excel.

Comment: could you provide a suggestion?  I've usually found my answers most easily by pasting my error messages to google, which then provides a direct link to Stackoverflow.  So I thought this was good, but an very open to better suggestions to finding a solution.

Comment: If the error is in the body, the search will pick it up. Maybe something like `R Readxl Error, EXPR must be a length 1 vector`. The title is difficult to read with all the error text clutter.

Comment: Why are you passing `NULL` to `read_excel()`? What exactly do you want to happen here?

Comment: that is the code generated by R studio when I click on the file. Im trying to load the file "automatically' with RS.  seems I always have trouble reading and writing excel with R.  I will read more documentation to figure out how to do it by typing in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second line, `read_excel` is expecting a filename.  Replace `read_excel(NULL)` with `read_excel("C:\\MyLocation\\MyFile")`.  But with your full filename and path, of course.